# Password Change Not Working (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to change my password on big Sur using recovery mode.(`resetpassword`  doesn’t work) I am using `dscl . -passwd /users/username` which comes up with the error:

Passwd: invalid path

<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)

If anyone knows a fix or another command I would be very grateful. I cannot log into any accounts on the computer so I can only use recovery mode commands in terminal.

Thanks.